# Bootstrap method initialization exception - Elasticsearch 7.8.0

Tags: elasticsearch-high-level-restclient

**Using java-high-level-rest client when we call getMapping for index or create index functions below errors get generated every time. almost for all the index related calls are generating this exception.**

```
bootstrap method initialization exception
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:194)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:315)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:259)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:249)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1883)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.lambda$performRequestAndParseEntity$9(RestHighLevelClient.java:1564)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1628)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1596)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1563)
at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.getMapping(IndicesClient.java:282)

Caused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:254)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:327)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.BootstrapMethodInvoker.invoke(BootstrapMethodInvoker.java:127)
```

I am using below environments

**elasticsearch - 7.8.0.
openJDK - 11 and 14, JDK 1.8
elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.8.0.jar and its dependencies included in pom.xml
Operation System : Tried both Windows 10 and Linux Mint.**

Answer (score 3):

i have get the same error, i found the httpcore version is not correct. my dependecy like this

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.16.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.16.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>7.16.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.12</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this because of a conflict with httpcore dependencies, in particular httpcore and httpcore-nio were incompatible. Dig into the pom of your elasticsearch-rest-client version and use the same versions as in there, or exclude them from your other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Change your pom.xml configuration

It may be that your elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client version is too high.

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

After I did this it was normal

Comment: While this _might_ help, can you explain why?